# Wordpress MySQL Query takes too much time to execute

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-design, entity-attribute-value

I am using `Wordpress 4.4.2`.

My Question is : In wordpress database I have a postmeta table with about 314,000 Records. When I am trying to execute following query (Build by wordpress) it takes about 5 - 10 Seconds to execute. I have about this kind of query in a single page like 2 - 3 times so takes 20 - 30 seconds to execute a single page:

```
SELECT hf_posts.ID
FROM hf_posts 
INNER JOIN hf_term_relationships
ON (hf_posts.ID = hf_term_relationships.object_id)

INNER JOIN hf_postmeta
ON ( hf_posts.ID = hf_postmeta.post_id ) 

INNER JOIN hf_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( hf_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 

INNER JOIN hf_postmeta AS mt2
ON ( hf_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )


WHERE 1=1 
AND ( hf_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (20) )
AND ( hf_postmeta.meta_key = 'match-date' 
AND ( ( mt1.meta_key = 'match-date'
AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '1460091523' ) 
AND ( mt2.meta_key = 'awaygame'
AND CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) = '0' ) ) )
AND hf_posts.post_type = 'match'
AND ((hf_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR hf_posts.post_status = 'future'))
GROUP BY hf_posts.ID
ORDER BY hf_postmeta.meta_value ASC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

I checked everything and I concluded that main problem is in postmeta table. Is there any solution that I can speed up this execution of query.

**Explain output :**

[image]

**SHOW CREATE TABLE OUTPUT :**

```
CREATE TABLE `hf_postmeta` (
 `meta_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `post_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `meta_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `meta_value` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
 PRIMARY KEY (`meta_id`),
 KEY `post_id` (`post_id`),
 KEY `meta_key` (`meta_key`(191)),
 KEY `meta_id` (`meta_id`),
 KEY `post_id_2` (`post_id`),
 KEY `meta_key_2` (`meta_key`),
 KEY `meta_key_3` (`meta_key`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=326766 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Looking forward to see your reply.

Regards,
Chirag

Comment: What does `explain select ...` says for this query, please add that into the question.

Comment: Alas, you are finding out one reason why EAV schemas suck.  Perhaps if you provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables, we could find some partial fix.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I edited the question

Comment: @RickJames I edited the question.

Comment: The query looks good and its using the indices,this could be some other issue.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I tried in my local pc it takes about the average 7 seconds same in the server !!

Answer (score 0):

(I had to prettyprint it to understand it...)

```
SELECT  p.ID
    FROM  hf_posts AS p
    INNER JOIN  hf_term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)
    INNER JOIN  hf_postmeta AS mt0 ON ( p.ID = mt0.post_id )
    INNER JOIN  hf_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( p.ID = mt1.post_id )
    INNER JOIN  hf_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( p.ID = mt2.post_id )
    WHERE  1=1
      AND  r.term_taxonomy_id IN (20)
      AND  mt0.meta_key = 'match-date'
      AND  mt1.meta_key = 'match-date'
      AND  CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) >= '1460091523'
      AND  mt2.meta_key = 'awaygame'
      AND  CAST(mt2.meta_value AS CHAR) = '0'
      AND  p.post_type = 'match'
      AND  (      p.post_status = 'publish'
              OR  p.post_status = 'future'
           )
    GROUP BY  p.ID
    ORDER BY  mt0.meta_value ASC
    LIMIT  0, 1
```

If possible, get rid of the first instance of `hf_postmeta`.  It seems to be there only to provide `meta_value` for ordering, yet you are fetching the same value via `mt1`.

If possible, get rid of `hf_posts`.  It seems to provide nothing.  Instead of `p.ID`, you could use `r.object_id`, which is known to be the same.

3 tables instead of 5 should help performance.

There are 3 redundant indexes in hf_postmeta, but you don't even have the two you need:

```
INDEX(post_id, meta_key)
INDEX(meta_key, post_id)
```

And `hf_term_relationships` needs

```
INDEX(term_taxonomy_id, object_id)
INDEX(object_id, term_taxonomy_id)
```